# How can I get an object is every response in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

### Context

I have an entity `User` and an entity `Cart` in my project. There is a `ManyToOne` relation between both entities :

```php
/* /src/Entity/User.php */

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Cart", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
*/
private $carts;
```

```php
/* /src/Entity/Cart.php */

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="carts")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $user;
```

I also have a method in my `CartRepository` that returns the current cart of the user.

```
/*src/Repository/CartRepository.php */

/**
* @param User $user
* @return mixed
* @throws NonUniqueResultException If the user somehow has several non-validated
* carts bidden to their account.
*/
public function findCurrentUserCart(User $user)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

### My Problem

What I would like to do is to be able to access easily the current count of cart items in the current user cart, so I can display it in my navbar. To do so, I need to be able to access the user's current cart easily.

I thought about getting it through the controller, but it seems quite annoying because, as the information is requested on all the pages of the site (because it is in the navbar) then I would need to retrieve the count from every single action of the controllers.

I then thought about having a simple function in my `User` entity like `getCartTotalCount()` but this would imply using the `CartRepository` directly from my `User` entity which, IMHO, feels wrong (I mean, my entity is a plain object and I don't feel like getting a repository is a good way to go, is it ?)

So my question is : **Is there a way to globally get the current cart object, so I can have it in all my views, without needing to passing it in any single `render()` method in my controllers ? Or maybe is there another way to go ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you’re using twig to render your templates, you have to create an extension.
Declaring a twig extension as a service you can inject the entity manager or the repository directly in the service constructor.

Here’s the documentation on symfony docs on how to create a twig extension: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

In this case you need to create a custom twig function.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the Twig extension looks like a feasible solution, I'd do it differently: using an embedded controller, you have more control. Place the cart template snippet in a distinct file, create a controller that renders this tiny piece, and call it using

```
{{ render(controller(
    'App\\Controller\\CartController::cartNavbar'
)) }}
```

If the template to display this information grows (for example, as you want to use an icon for an empty cart, and another one if something is placed in the cart), you will see that this helps to seperate concerns better than using an extension